# Equivalent to Google "my maps" for larger datasets, access-restricted webmap without a custom website

Tags: google-maps, kml, web-mapping, software-recommendations

I know how to upload a KML file to create a google "my map" and share it privately via Google Drive. I want to know how I can do this for larger datasets that exceed the Google "my map" limits.  I am willing to pay for this service, but I do not want to become a web programmer or have to make and host a custom website.  I tried to look at "Google Maps Platform" but it is way over my head as I do not want to create a new website from scratch.  I can't use ArcGIS because the people I would want to share with will not have ArcGIS accounts (which are way too expensive for this purpose).

For example, let's imagine a point layer with 100,000 points, each of which have 4 attributes.  I want to be able to view the points over something that looks like Google Maps satellite view.  I want to share the map with 3-5 people via a password or logins.  I want viewers to be able to interact with the data by zooming in and out and viewing the attributes when clicking on a point.  I just want to pay for the exact thing I can do in 5 minutes with Google My Maps but for a larger dataset.  Anyone know of a way?

Comment: For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Imagine a $500 project for a nonprofit.  Basically I am looking for a private file sharing option to show a GIS layer (too big for a static map image) to a few non-GIS users.  This is often an iterative process, so I can't hire someone else every time there is a new draft to review.  My current workarounds are either splitting the layer into subsets of <10,000 features to show on multiple google maps in Google Drive or using QGIStoWeb to create an HTML file I can email in a zip folder.  But QGIStoWeb only works for me about 50% of the time.   I'm not trying to make webmaps for lots of users.

Answer (score 0):

There are companies that might suit your case, for example:

- Felt: https://felt.com/create-a-map
- Carto: https://carto.com/
- Mapbox: https://www.mapbox.com/

They mostly have free tier options so you can try it out and then you may have to pay for your size of dataset or for having a private map that only your chosen few can see. You'll need to read the small print for each provider to make sure. We don't know your budget or precise user requirements.

Failing that you might want to find a friendly web map developer consultant to do the job for you.

Comment: I had not heard of Felt but can't even find pricing for it and non-transparent pricing is most certainly beyond the budget for the kinds of small projects where I have this need.  Carto is too expensive at over $1,500/year.  I have a Mapbox account but have not figured out anything that is comparable to the 5-minute google map option.

Comment: I was wrong about Carto, it is far more expensive than I thought.  The >$1,500 price was from a third-party website so I decided to try to confirm that there was not a lower-cost tier for occasional use.  After registering a trial account, no pricing info was shown.  It took me several days and multiple emails with Carto support to finally get someone to tell me that the starting price for a single-user license is $12,000 !?!  So, um, that is not going to work for me.

Comment: I think we've found a way you can do what you want by paying for it, but the market price seems to be above what you want to pay. If it could be done for $500, people would be doing it. Send me a message (twitter link in profile here and email contact in web site linked also) and if your non-profit is something I agree with I'll see what can be done.